# Magento "shipping method - flat rate" showing 0 on checkout page

Tags: php, magento

I have set a fixed flat rate for shipping method on Magento shipping method configuration but when I checkout, the flat rate is 0 on SHIPPING METHOD - CHECKOUT PAGE !! Please check attachment. Seeking help from experts !!

Screen shot of Magento Checkout page and Shipping method configuration page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m8qd.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkm03.jpg

Comment: Have you made sure you are amending the correct configuration scope? Your screenshot shows you editing default scope, but the indicator next to that value shows "website" scope

Comment: Have you installed magento with sample data?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have installed magento with sample data. If you have installed magento with sample data.This happens.

There is a shopping cart rule with name `Free shipping on all orders over $500`

From admin panel go to `Promotions/Shopping Cart Price Rules` find above rule of may be any other rule that can cause this issue.

Click on rule to edit in our case we have this`Free shipping on all orders over $500` rule. Go inside and change `status to Inactive` and save rule.

Now it will show rate.